# cannot convert argument 1 from '_Value_type' to 'swo::tree'

Tags: c++, sorting, stdlist

I wanted to sort a list by the list.sort() function, to make this sort work i wanted to make it use my own sort:

```
l->sort([](tree& a, tree& b) {
        return  a.getDataToCompare() < b.getDataToCompare();
    });
```

getDataToCompare returns me the frequency of the node

```
double tree::getDataToCompare() const {
    return this->node->getDataToCompare();
}
```

but i keep getting this error and i dont know how to get rid of it:

Error   C2664   'bool swo::listnode::convertToTreeList::<lambda_d1aa4c1f1bdda9705501f18ede41e8ec>::operator ()(swo::tree,swo::tree) const': cannot convert argument 1 from '_Value_type' to 'swo::tree' huffman C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\xutility    1614

Comment: `tree& a, tree& b` should be `const tree& a, const tree& b`

Comment: what is the type of 'l' ?

Comment: i tried it with const but it did not make any difference at all

l --> std::list<tree*>* l = new std::list<tree*>();

Comment: Since you have a list of `tree*`, your comparison predicate should also take `tree*`.